# Json.Net Post Issue

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I am new to working with Json documents.  I am working with the Team Dynamix API and trying to create a new Asset.  I am using ARC (Advanced REST client) to write test requests.  I can write a successful ARC request but struggling to write the actual code with C# and Json.Net.  If I serialize my C# request, it looks the same as the ARC request.  Here is  a bit of my code:

```
Asset newAsset = new Asset{
    //attributes of asset here
}
responseMsg = await oHttpClientX.PostAsJsonAsync(addAssetUri, newAsset);
```

The response is:

```
"The following errors were encountered:\r\n * AssetRole is required.
```

I was receiving this response in my ARC request but I added the correct features to newAsset to fix it.  Maybe this question is too specific but I thought I would ask.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: I don't understand.  Did you fix your issue or not?  What are you asking?

Comment: The question is not clear, did you manage to call the api from outside C# but when calling it from C# you encountered that error? It seems that you are missing a property of the object, but can't be sure, we'll need more info to help out

Comment: @KinSlayerUY Yes. I can successfully call to the API from outside C# but when I make the same exact call to the API in C# I get the same issue.  I need to serialize before posting correct?  That may be the issue... will update after I try.

Comment: Wait... I definitely shouldn't serialize.

Comment: REST clients typically do their own serialization.

Comment: @BrianSunbury you should test what the Asset is serialized to before is sent. And try to send the request as a string if the serialization is correct. The issue may be inside the REST client serialization.

Comment: Came back to the program today.  I created a new asset and tested the code again. It worked today so I think it was an issue with how i formatted my Asset object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for.  After looking at other API documentation and reading Json.NET documentation I was able to create the asset.  It looks like this:

```
Asset asset = new Asset {
    StatusID = 1067,
    Name = "computerName",
    Attributes = new List<CustomAttribute> {
        new CustomAttribute{
            Name ="AssetRole",
            ID=12345,
            Choices = new List<CustomAttributeChoice>{
                new CustomAttributeChoice{
                    ID=71745,
                    Name="Staff"
                }
            },
            Value="71745",
            ValueText="Staff",
            ChoicesText="Staff"
        }
    }
};
```